# Jquery disables css :hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several linked photos that are set to be (opacity: 0.45) except on hover and when clicked (opacity:1). I also have a JQuery function listening for clicks, which will then change the css of the clicked photo to be (opacity:1) and the rest back to (opacity: 0.45). However once the function runs the hover effect is disabled somehow. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<a class="img_thumbs"><img src="someimage.jpg"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.img_thumbs:hover {
      opacity:1;
}

.img_thumbs {
      opacity:0.45;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.img_thumbs').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.img_thumbs').css({'opacity': '0.45'});
    $(this).css({'opacity': '1'});
}):
```

I have tried:

- adding the JQuery .hover() effect in and outside of the  function
- changing the selectors, css, html to a.img_thumbs, individually and together
- looking for where the code fails

That function also runs an AJAX call and several other listeners, but ive determined they do not have any adverse effects (commented them out), so the problem lies only in the code I've provided.

An alternate solution would also be gratefully accepted, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible to provide jsfiddle? Thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C8R7f/ its not working as i have it..

Comment: So currently your problem is the hover opacity not working after clicking on the image? Your jsfiddle seems working though.

Comment: well in my actual project when i select a photo it changes the opacity to 1 and the other photos remain opaque, but then the hover effect no longer works...  http://jsfiddle.net/C8R7f/1/

Comment: Wondering why are you are doing the prevent default on clicking an img? Maybe that is messing with it, could try taking it out.

Comment: prevent default because that function also runs an AJAX call, if i take it out it reloads the page so it would work, but then the AJAX wouldnt, plus i dont want the page to jump back to the top as it would in a reload

Comment: if you mean the file being called by AJAX its not an aspx.cs file its .php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

CSS:

```
.img_thumbs:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
.active {
      opacity:1 !important;
}
.img_thumbs {
      opacity:0.45;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.img_thumbs').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.img_thumbs').removeClass( "active" )
    $(this).addClass( "active" );
});
```

The tips is use other active class, and add or remove this class, when click.

Comment: In your code the state of click element was not registred, therefore the strange behavior

Comment: "!important" overwrites the other css created by jQuery